# Ingress ignoring Global IP when making it https only

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

Create an External Ingress for a service like the one below.

Everything gets created but without the behavior I expect.

- Global IP is not used, another one is used instead
- HTTP is still enabled

```yaml
apiVersion: "extensions/v1beta1"
kind: "Ingress"
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: false
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "my-ingress-ip"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: "my-service-api"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: "pulumi"
    app.kubernetes.io/name: "my-service-api"
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.0.0-service"
    helm.sh/chart: "service-0.1.0"
  name: "my-service-api-proxy"
  namespace: "load-test"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: "my-service-api-proxy"
    servicePort: 80
  tls:
    - secretName: "my-tls-secret-cert"
```

As soon as I remove the kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http annotation, the ingress picks up my global IP.

Has anyone ran into this issue when creating an Ingress with a global IP and HTTPS only access?

GKE version:  1.18.16-gke.2100

Node Config:

> Kernel version    5.4.89+
>
> OS image    Container-Optimized OS from Google
>
> Container runtime version    docker://19.3.14
>
> kubelet version    v1.18.16-gke.2100
>
> kube-proxy version    v1.18.16-gke.2100

Comment: Updated my descriptor using quotes and the Global IP works, but for some reason, it still allows HTTP traffic.

Answer (score 1):

This works, remember to use quotes on all annotation values since they are strings.

```yaml
apiVersion: "extensions/v1beta1"
kind: "Ingress"
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "my-ingress-ip"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: "my-service-api"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: "pulumi"
    app.kubernetes.io/name: "my-service-api"
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.0.0-service"
    helm.sh/chart: "service-0.1.0"
  name: "my-service-api-proxy"
  namespace: "load-test"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: "my-service-api-proxy"
    servicePort: 80
  tls:
    - secretName: "my-tls-secret-cert"
```

Also if you are updating an existing Ingress, give it a few minutes (like 10) for it to pick up the changes